# Auto populating Account Name in Community

Tags: community

When I log into Community as Customer User and i create new case, I want Account name to be auto populated from which i logged into as customer Community User.
Can anybody please help me to achieve the same.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Is your community user the owner of the case when it's created?

Comment: No, the Community user isn't owner of the case. I have in mind to create a custom button. But i really dont know whether it will work or not. i have done this type of auto populating for non community users

Comment: The issue you'll face is that the account of the community user won't be in User, but instead will be in the User's contact info. That would require a controller extension to get that from User.contact in order to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

When the Community User logs a case, they are automatically associated in the Name field (the Lookup(Contact) and the Account field is always automatically filled in based on the related Contact.